# Error en Python con conexión a postgreSQL

Tags: python-3.x, base-de-datos, postgresql, vscode

Hola soy muy nuevo en python y estoy tratando de conectarlo con una base de datos de Postgres con el siguiente código:

```
import psycopg2
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
        host = "localhost",
        user = "postgres",
        password = "xxx",)
except:
    pass

try:
    print (conn)
    print (type(conn))
except NameError:
    print("error en la conexión")
```

y me sale este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 1, in <module>
    psycopg2
NameError: name 'psycopg2' is not defined
```

Comment: Instalaste previamente el módulo psycopg2 en Python?

Comment: Si lo tengo instalado, no me hadado ningún error eso

Answer (score 0):

- Como comentan, necesitas instalar psycopg2, el paquete que usa Python para conectar con Postgres. Puedes correr `pip3 install psycopg2` para esto.
- Si estás en un entorno Linux, debes tener las herramientas de desarrollo instaladas (build-essential en Ubuntu, grupo "Developer Tools" en Fedora) y libpq-dev para que Python pueda instalar correctamente el paquete.

Comment: Lo tengo instalado lo vuelvo a instalar y me sale esto; Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2 in c:\users\chonond\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (2.8.5)
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: Existe la posibilidad de que estés usando el comando "python" en lugar de "python3" para ejecutar tu programa? Si tienes instalado el módulo en python3 pero ejecutas tu programa solo escribiendo "python", el intérprete no encontrará el módulo.